DuckDB, Django and apache2 Permission Denied in production
I have a problem with my duckdb database, that I really don't seem to understand.
After I created a .db database and put it in the apache2/Django webapp root and gave www-data access to it and its directory, I still get permission denied.
Here's the weird part(s):

I don't get the permission error when I establish the connection, I only get it in the fetchdf() part.

con = duckdb(database='path/to/db.db',read_only=True)

P = con.execute('SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 1;')

p = p.fetchdf() # Here's where the error gets thrown

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
duckdb.duckdb.IOException: IO Error: Permission denied


When I run the same python code with the www-data, everything works nice. Also in the runserver situation it works without a problem. It seems that the issue is related the production environment.

I suspect that duckdb wants access to a certain directory or file that I have to make available in the apache2 config, but me and AI didn't know what or where.
Any help?
I tried changing the temp_directory, home_directory, extension_directory, and secret_directory to a directory within the webapp root directory.
I tried moving the db file to a different dir and gave apache permission to it also in the .conf.

Looks like a SELinux problem, if you've already tried adjusting file permissions and the permission denied error persists, it's very likely that SELinux is blocking access.
You can try the following commands to check if SELinux is blocking the access and fix the problem:
sudo ausearch -c 'python' --raw | audit2allow -M duckdb_access
sudo semodule -i duckdb_access.pp

sudo ausearch -c 'python' --raw | audit2allow -M duckdb_access: This command searches the SELinux audit logs for any access denials that the python process has encountered. It then uses audit2allow to generate an SELinux policy module named duckdb_access (can be another name, I just choose that name) containing rules to allow these accesses.
sudo semodule -i duckdb_access.pp: Installs the generate policy generated policy module (duckdb_access.pp) allowing python to execute the process.
If this resolves the issue, you'll know SELinux was the cause of the error.

Hi Leonardo!
thanks for the answer. No there's nothing logged for SELinux.
I solved the problem in that I moved the duchdb.connect('db.db') out of the settings.py of django to each view separatly. I really don't know why this happened.
